# removeEventListener with defined functions

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I try to remove event listeners with defined functions, but I don't know why `removeEventListener` lost the function references.

If I set the `eventOnMouseOver` and `eventOnMouseOut` out the test closure, then works fine.

Do not have "test" the same reference and then their functions too, each time is called?

Can someone explain me why?

```js
function test(value) {

  var element = document.querySelector('h1');

  if (value) {
    console.log('Enabling listeners');
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', eventOnMouseOver);
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', eventOnMouseOut);

  } else {
    console.log('trying to remove listeners...');
    element.removeEventListener('mouseover', eventOnMouseOver);
    element.removeEventListener('mouseout', eventOnMouseOut);
  }

  function eventOnMouseOver(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.classList.add('selected');
  }

  function eventOnMouseOut() {
    this.classList.remove('selected');
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <input type="button" value="enable" onclick="test(true)" />
  <input type="button" value="disable" onclick="test(false)" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're making new functions every time you go to add/remove, so you're actually attempting to remove *different* functions than the ones you added. Define those functions so that they're reused with every call. In other words, put them *outside* the `test()` function.